# Missing params in Ajax Post request in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, missing-data

I am trying to make an Ajax post request and pass params to use them in a query, but my params are always empty. Here is my code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
});

function searchPatient(){
    var params = {
        'name'      : $("#input-search-name").val(),
        'lastname'  : $("#input-search-lastname").val() 
    }
    console.log($('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
    $.ajax({
        data        :  params,
        url         : '{{ route("searchPatient") }}',
        contentType: "application/json",
        type        : 'post',
        beforeSend  : function(){
            console.log(params);
        },
        success     : function(data){
            //Inserto a la tabla principal el contenido
            $("#main-table-patients").html(data);
            //alert('exito');
        },
        error       : function(xhr, status, error) {
              var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
              console.error(err.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

And this is my web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'], function(){
  Route::namespace('Patient')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('/patients','PatientController');
    Route::post('/patients/search/{name?}/{lastname?}','PatientController@search')->name('searchPatient');
  });
});
```

And this is my method in my controller

```
public function search($name = '', $lastname = '')
{
  $patients = '';
  $patients = Patient::where('name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')
      ->Where('lastName','like','%'.$lastname.'%');

  return $name.' and '.$lastname;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an expected behaviour. You are sending in POST the variables but your route is designed to retrive the variables from the url.
Decide what you want ... 
if you want to pass them in POST then your ajax call's url should be `/patients/search`
and your route should be only

```
Route::post('/patients/search','PatientController@search');
```

your controller at that point can deal with $request object

```
public function search(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    dd($request->all());
}
```

if you want to pass them in the url (not a good idea IMHO)
then change your ajax call url to:

```
url: '/patients/search/' + params.name + "/" + params.lastname
```

This approach can cause problems in case one of the 2 params contains a "slash" (/)

Comment: Thanks it works, I decided to use the first way. I also had to delete: "content type: application/json" in my AJAX request.