# Ajax call has only the token in the response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using Laravel with Ajax.
I am trying to make a Ajax call to a controller. I did a `print_r` on the `$request`, but I only have the token in the array, no other data.
I've tried playing around with the data object in the Ajax call which never appears in the request.

**View:**

```
@section('head')
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
@endsection
<div>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/test.js') }}"></script>
```

**test.js**

```
 $( document ).ready(function() 
    {
        $( "#submit" ).click(function() 
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type:'POST',
                url:'{{ route("test") }}',
                data:{test: "test"},
                success:function(data) 
                {
                    console.log(data.msg);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Session;

class testController extends Controller
{

    public function test(Request $request)
    {
     $data = $request->all();
     print_r($data);
   }
 }
```

**The Results**

```
Array ( [_token] => fKmSJpY0DRyCqzXyDPo2LwiJSD1wEiThVYn29lX7)
```

Comment: It's probably that your test route is set as GET and you're POSTing. See this answer for example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53088426/3585500

Answer (score -1):

I would try moving

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
}
});
```

into the `$( document ).ready(function()`

I think could be scope issue. Try that and see if it works.